# Headless Selenium driver unable to find Firefox binary even when specified in code and $PATH on Shared Web Host

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, shared-hosting, headless-browser

## Goal

I am trying to get Selenium to run Firefox headless on my virtual python environment on my Dreamhost shared web host.

## Problem

The selenium driver is unable to find my Firefox binary even though I have specified its path in my code and have added it to my PATH.

## Information

I unpacked 64-bit firefox 46.0.1 tar to ~/bin/firefox. 
I have also ran `chmod 777 ~/bin/firefox/firefox`.
I do not have sudo access.

```
[SharedWebServer]$ cat ~/.bashrc
    export PATH="$PATH:~/bin/firefox"
    alias firefox="~/bin/firefox/firefox"
    alias pythonactivate='source $HOME/<DOMAIN>/env/bin/activate'
[SharedWebServer]$ hash
    hits    command
    0       /home/<user>/bin/firefox/firefox
[SharedWebServer]$ which firefox
[SharedWebServer]$
[SharedWebServer]$ export DISPLAY=:10
[SharedWebServer]$ export
    declare -x DISPLAY=":10"
    declare -x GEM_HOME="/home/<user>/.gems"
    declare -x GEM_PATH="/home/<user>/.gems:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"
    declare -x HOME="/home/<user>"
    declare -x LC_COLLATE="C"
    declare -x LOGNAME="<user>"
    declare -x MAIL="/home/<user>/Maildir/"
    declare -x OLDPWD
    declare -x PATH="/home/<user>/.gems/bin:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/games"
    declare -x PS1="[\\h]\$ "
    declare -x PWD="/home/<user>"
    declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
    declare -x SHLVL="1"
    declare -x SSH_CLIENT="<blah>"
    declare -x SSH_CONNECTION="<blah>"
    declare -x SSH_TTY="/dev/pts/1"
    declare -x TERM="xterm"
    declare -x USER="<user>"
```

## Code

```
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(firefox_path='/home/<user>/bin/firefox/firefox')
firefox_profile = custom_firefox_profile(images=False, css=True, flash=False)
driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary,firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
vdisplay = Xvfb()
vdisplay.start()
```

## Error

" Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")

RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox

#### The actual error block:

```
[SharedWebServer]$ source $HOME/<DOMAIN>/env/bin/activate
(env)[SharedWebServer]$ python main.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 238, in <module>
  sys.exit(main())
File "main.py", line 71, in main
  driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=firefox_binary,firefox_profile=firefox_profile)
File "/home/<user>/<domain>/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
  firefox_options.binary_location = self.binary if isinstance(self.binary, basestring) else self.binary._get_firefox_start_cmd()
File "/home/<user>/<domain>/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 163, in _get_firefox_start_cmd

" Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox")
RuntimeError: Could not find firefox in your system PATH. Please specify the firefox binary location or install firefox
```

Comment: Running firefox headlessly can be tricky. For a better experience you could use Phantomjs.
Regarding your error try reopening the ssh and `export DISPLAY=:10` before running the script

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida `For a better experience you could use Phantomjs` is a bad advice. Phantomjs has its uses, but cannot be compared to testing on real browser.

Comment: @GabrielFair when you run `which firefox` under the same user account as used for running test, does it return a proper path?

Comment: I had not heard of Phantomjs. I will look into it. I have updated my #information above with the "null" results of `which firefox` and `export DISPLAY=:10`

Comment: Can you try `driver=webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary='/home/<user>/bin/firefox/firefox', firefox_profile=firefox_profile)` ? Had a quick read of the code and looks like that may do what you need